# Python Dictionary from External file

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, import, external

I am trying to make a dictionary in Python, but I do not know how to do two things.

1. When I search for keywords in a dictionary, instead of just looking for direct matches, I would like it to find every word that has the keywords in it. E.G. Search: Cat - Results: Cat, Allocate.
2. I would like the dictionary to load an external file, so new terms that I add to the dictionary can be saved when I load it up afterwards.

Comment: And the problem with your code is?

Comment: When I search cat it only comes up with Cat, and not cat and allocate. 
After I close my file the new results that I add to the dictionary are not saved.

Comment: you could loop through the dictionary keys and check if it contains the word.

Comment: you will need to open a file, write the dictionary content on the file, then close the file, in order to persist the content of your dictionary. This is because the dictionary is created fresh every time you start the program

Comment: For future reference, try to avoid using built-ins like `dict` as variable names. It makes the code confusing to read and can cause hard-to-diagnose bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following methods:
For 1.

```
print ("Welcome back to the dictionary");

dict = {"CAT": "A small four legged animal that likes to eat mice",
        "DOG": "A small four legged animal that likes to chase cats",
        "ALLOCATE": "to give something to someone as ​their ​share of a ​total ​amount, to use in a ​particular way",
        }

def Dictionary():
    x = input("\n\nEnter a word: \n>>>");
    x = x.upper();
    found = False
    for y in dict:
        if x in y:
            found = True
            print (x,":",dict[x])
            Dictionary()
            break
    if not found:
        y = input ("Unable to find word. Enter a new definition of your word: \n>>>");
        dict.update({x:y})
        Dictionary()
Dictionary()
```

For 2: You can load data directly from a json file

```
import json
dict = {}
with open("test.json", "r") as config_file:
    dict = json.load(config_file)
```

where test.json being your file for e.g.
test.json

```
{"CAT": "A small four legged animal that likes to eat mice",
        "DOG": "A small four legged animal that likes to chase cats",
        "ALLOCATE": "to give something to someone as ​their ​share of a ​total ​amount, to use in a ​particular way",
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should let you match cat in allocate.

```
for key in dict.keys():
    if x in key:
        do some stuff
```